# How to dump result of a sql query into a file

Tags: mysql, database-backups

Ok so I am in a situation where I need to dump the results of a sql query into a file and this is for backup purpose I tried running th following from my terminal :

```
mysql -e "select * from products where brand_id=5" -u root -p database_name > dumpfile.sql
```

this dumps the data but with the "insert into statements", so if later on I want to dump this data back into my database I will be re-composing it. And that is not the correct approach. So please suggest me how do I dump query results for back up purpose ?

Comment: do you need to dump result of select query ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following command line (using [`--where`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) option) should work:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name products --where="brand_id=5" > dumpfile.sql
```

More information about the `mysqldump` command: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 3):

use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

> mysqldump -u root -p database_name products --where "brand_id=5">
>   dump.sql

For more read: 
http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2012/11/15/3-methods-to-extract-a-subset-of-your-data-using-mysqldump/