# How to save SQL query results as a list of INSERT statements into a .sql file

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-dump

I am working on a PostgreSQL database. I would like to get the results of a `SELECT` query as a list of `INSERT` statements and have them saved into a `.sql` file (let's say `exported_data.sql`).

This is because later I would like to run the `.sql` file on another database and have the data "imported" in the table, so that the table gets "updated".

```
psql my_database -h my_host < exported_data.sql
```

Let's say my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM params_table 
WHERE params_type = 'tkt';
```

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script) I see that [one way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12816187/7658051) is to:

1. Create a temporary table filled with the results of the query

   ```
    CREATE TABLE temporary_table 
    AS 
        SELECT *
        FROM params_table
        WHERE params_type  = 'tkt';
   ```
2. Export the table as a list of `INSERT` statements into a `.sql` file

   ```
    pg_dump --table=temporary_table --data-only --column-inserts my_database -h my_host > exported_data.sql
   ```
3. Remove the table, to keep the database clean.

   ```
    DROP TABLE temporary_table;
   ```

Is there a way to do it in one shot?

I am asking just because I would not like to create and then remove a temporary table every time I need to export some data.

I saw from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34872966/7658051) that for a MySQL database it is possible to do it one-shot:

```
mysqldump -u root -p my_database -h my_host params_table --where="params_type  = 'tkt'" > exported_data.sql
```

So I have read the [Postgresql documentation for `pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html), but I cannot find any equivalent for `--where` clause.

Comment: A TEMP table is automatically removed at end of session. And there is `copy` / `\cpy`, too

Comment: @wildplasser, except Tms91 is not actually using a `temporary`  table just calling it that.  An actual `temporary` table would not work in any case as they are session specific and the `pg_dump` session would not see it. `COPY` and/or `\copy` do not output `INSERT`s.

Comment: Is it always the same table, and how many columns are you interested in?

Comment: @codeulike I would like to know the most general way to do it, so it would be great if someone could point me a way to generate a list-of-insert-.sql-file containing `INSERT`s into different tables and updating more than one column. But any help is appreciated.